# Normalization of phonon density of states

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phonons, density-of-states, density-functional-theory

Analogous to electronic structure calculations, we can solve for dispersion band structure of phonons for lattices using harmonic lattice approx. And we can find the so-called phonon density of states (DOS) distribution $g(\omega)$ as a function of frequency $\omega$. In 3D space, some implementations of density functional perturbation theory (DFPT) tend to normalize the integral of $\int g(\omega)d\omega$ to $3N$ with $N$ being the number of atoms in an unit cell of the lattice. I understand that in the classical formulation of molecular vibrations, a $N-$atom molecule in d-dimensional space has $dN$ “normal modes”. But for crystals of infinite sizes, dose it make sense to make $\int g(\omega)d\omega=3N$? Do we have the liberty to normalize the DOS distribution to any number so that the calculation of thermodynamic properties based on DOS is correct? For example, can we normalize the DOS distribution so that the calculation of constant volume heat capacity $C_V$ has a limit of 3R at high temperature (Dulong-Petit law)?

Different implementations of modern DFT packages seem to normalize phonon DOS in different way. The package [here](http://computingformaterials) normalize it to 1. While quantum espresso normalize it to 6 times atom number in a unit cell. Can any one tell me how should we normalize the phonon DOS for lattices in general? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decisions about the normalization of the density of states are largely arbitrary, provided

1. the choice is clearly stated;
2. the correct role of intensive and extensive properties is preserved.

If the normalization has been chosen as $\int g(\omega)d\omega= 3N$, it is clear that for an infinite crystal $\int g(\omega)d\omega= \infty$. However, this is consistent with the fact that also the total (extensive) energy of an infinite crystal is infinite. What should remain finite is the density f states *per unit volume* or *per particle*, precisely as the energy per unit volume or the energy per particle remains finite even for an infinite crystal.